# Class function returns promise $$state object instead of plain object?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-promise

This question has similar pre-existing questions, but I don't find them to be the same due to the nature of ES6 classes.

I have a service that returns an object, but it returns it as a promise state object instead of a plain object, so the data isn't accessible.

Below I show how I call the function, and return from both the promise and the function, but the returning function returns a $q promise instead of the internal returned data.

```
class EnterpriseController {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor(EnterpriseService, $scope) {
    this.name = 'enterprise';
    this.systemId = 20003
    this.pageLink = '#/enterprise';
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.EnterpriseService = EnterpriseService;
    this.$scope.data = this.getEnterpriseData();
  }

  getEnterpriseData() {
    this.EnterpriseService.getData().then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }
}

EnterpriseController.$inject = ["EnterpriseService", "$scope"];
export default EnterpriseController;
```

returns:

[image]

nothing below the $$state level is accessible. `$$state.value` returns undefined.

Ultimately, I want access to the returned data in the constructor, yet I only have access to what seems to be the $q promise.

Comment: it's an promise witch you need to resolve.

Comment: @CharlesWaston i thought it was fix now??

Comment: It is still undefined.

Comment: but before you had $$state object from this.scope.data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an promise witch you need to resolve. You are returning an promise from getEnterpriseData() method

from

```
constructor(EnterpriseService, $scope) {
    this.name = 'enterprise';
    this.systemId = 20003
    this.pageLink = '#/enterprise';
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.EnterpriseService = EnterpriseService;
    this.$scope.data = this.getEnterpriseData();
  }

  getEnterpriseData() {
   return this.EnterpriseService.getData().then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }
```

To

```
  constructor(EnterpriseService, $scope) {
    this.name = 'enterprise';
    this.systemId = 20003
    this.pageLink = '#/enterprise';
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.EnterpriseService = EnterpriseService;
     this.getEnterpriseData().then(function(data){
      this.$scope.data = data;
      console.log(this.$scope.data)
     });
  }

  getEnterpriseData() {
   return this.EnterpriseService.getData().then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: so do what exactly?

`getEnterpriseData() {
    this.EnterpriseService.getData().then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
}`

Comment: try this
 this.getEnterpriseData().then(function(data){
    this.$scope.data = data;
console.log(this.$scope.data)
});

Comment: yes that should also work if you are return resolved data

Comment: Neither of those work. The first option is incorrect because "this.getEnterpriseData()" is using "this" in the wrong context as broken down in the official MDN page: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

The second option simply returns "undefined"

Comment: As far as I am aware, the "this" in the ES6 class is not referencing the correct context.

Comment: i don't think you need to do use this for EnterpriseService
 getEnterpriseData() {
    EnterpriseService.getData().then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120168/discussion-between-jorawar-singh-and-charles-watson).

Comment: who is consuming this data, some controls are promise aware and you could just return the promise..

Comment: The data gets called from a service, passed to the controller, and I simply want the data accessible in my view so I attempt to put it on $scope. But it only console.logs. If I return it, it shows "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The solution!

I simply needed to capture $scope in the initial class context, so line 13 solved the problem:

[image]